# org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In spring mvc I want to save the data into mysql data base with hibernate and also want to fetch the data by email.
In my data base I have the table users table with the fields:-`(id(bigint),name(varchar),username(varchar),password(varchar))`
I have the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,BindingResult result) {

         userService.addUser(user.getName(),user.getUsername(),user.getEmail(),user.getPassword());


            java.util.List<User> user1== userService.getUserinfo(user.getEmail());

                      userService.display(user1);
}
```

UserDao.java is:

```
public interface UserDao {

    public void saveUser ( User user );

     public  List<User> getUserinfo(String email);
}
```

UserDaoImpl is:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

public void saveUser(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

public  List<User>  getUserinfo(String email) {

        String hql = "select * from users where email = :email";
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
            .setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();

    return users;
    }

}
```

UserService.java is:

```
public interface UserService {


    User addUser(String name, String username, String email, String password);

       public List<User> getUserinfo(String email);

}
```

UserServiceImpl is:

```
 public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public User addUser(String name, String username, String email, String password) {


            User user = new User(name,username, email,password);

            userDao.saveUser(user);

            return user;
                }


  public List<User> getUserinfo(String email) {         
            return userDao.getUserinfo(email);
        }
    }
```

User.java is:

```
     @Entity
        @Table(name = "users")
        public class User {

    @Column(name = "id")    
        private long userId;

    @Column(name = "name")  
            private String Name;

    @Column(name = "username")  
            private String username;

    @Column(name = "email") 
            private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")  
            private String password;
//constructors
        //setters and getters
        }
```

data is stored in to the database but when I fetching
 the error is showing is:

```
 com.news.User cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Comment: Show your entity class (`com.news.User`)and the complete stacktrace. All other code is not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message of the exception is crystal clear. The ID of the User class is of type Long, and you're trying to get a User by ID by passing its email as argument, of type String. That can't possibly work.

If your goal is to find a user by email, then you need a query, such as

```
select u from User u where u.email = :email
```

Comment: how I have to store the data?? as list??what will be the return type??how I have use this?

Comment: Querying is stuff you absolutely need to properly learn. Using Hibernate without knowing how to query is like programming without knowing loops. Read the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql

Comment: I have updated the question..I am using what you have said..now the error is:-- com.news.User cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: uniqueResult(), as its name, its javadoc, and error message you get indicate, returns a unique result. Not a list of multiple results. So what it returns is ONE User.

Comment: so,I have to use list()...I have a question here, In controller class :--userService.display(user1);..where user1 is a list which contains the data..how can I fetch these data inside the "userService.display()" method??

Comment: You need to use list() if multiple users can have the same email address and the goal is to get all the users having an email address. If only one user can have an email address, then uniqueResult() is the appropriate method: it will return the user which has the given email address, or null if no user has that email address. Don't use SQL. Use HQL. I don't understand your last question: you're passing the list of users as argument to display(), so the method has the list of users to display in its argument.

Comment: in the display method I want to display the corresponding value of the fields(id,name,password) where email= user.getEmail();

so in dispaly method how can I fetch these data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, email);
```

This `get` expect a class name and an "ID" (in your case user id is a `Long`). You probably should use [some kind of request](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html#find(java.lang.String)) to find an user by email.

Comment: I have updated the question..I am using what you have said..now the error is:-- com.news.User cannot be cast to java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

The snippet

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql).setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();
```

returns an object. (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult())

You should probably change it to

```
User user = (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();
```

Also, do you have to change the return type of the method to User, after all you are getting the info of a single user. You don't need a List there

Comment: I have used this code..I am getting the error:----java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.news.User in the line :---User user = (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)

Comment: Did you add the complete snippet? --User user = (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();